# How to go back from %%script python --no-raise-error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I ran at some point %%script python --no-raise-error and now I want to go back and stop when there is an error.

I restarted the kernel, the notebook, even the computer but when running all, it still doesn't stop when facing an error.

Maybe at some point I might have done something else because I was trying advice from the forums on how to avoid stopping from errors and now cant go back.